# Python: Lambda one row input + calculation

Tags: python, lambda, split

I can't understand, how I can write this in one row:

```
a, b = input().split(' ')
print(int(a) + int(b))
```

In my mind function looks like this:

```
print((lambda a, b: a + b)('{0}, {1}'.format(input().split())))
```

Python returns "tuple index out of range". I tried to find solution of My problem, but I don't understand how to google it.
Can You write Me please where My code is wrong or could You advise Me the right words for googling.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
print(sum(int(ai) for ai in input().split()))
```

**Output**

```
1 2  # input
3
```

Using a lambda function for this is not as readable (or general), but it can be done as below:

```
print((lambda a, b: a + b)(*(int(ai) for ai in input().split())))
```

To learn more about this topics, read:

- [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)
- [Unpacking](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/) to understand what the `*` is doing
- [Generator Expressions PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to deep dive into the nitty gritty details of generator expressions

Comment: @phaestos Glad I could help! If my answer solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted, to signal others that your problem was solved.